# Not able to visible button asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I am not able to visible my button on another button click event.

**.aspx**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnActivate" runat="server" SkinID="skinLoginButton"
    Text="Activate" ToolTip="Activate" CausesValidation="true"
    ValidationGroup="UserAuthentication" onclick="btnActivate_Click" />

<asp:Button ID="btnhomepage" Visible="false" runat="server" 
    Text="Goto Homepage" CssClass="cssLoginButton" onclick="btnhomepage_Click"/>
```

**.cs**

```
#region btnActivate_Click
    protected void btnActivate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.btnhomepage.Visible = true;
    }
    #endregion
```

I use `this.btnhomepage.Visible = true;` in **.cs** file.

what's wrong in my code or declearation?

Comment: Add your other button declaration and its event handler where you use this piece of code.

Comment: Can you also include the Css Class "cssLoginButton" as this may include a display attribute with !important.

Comment: @thedixon I used display:inline property in cssLginButton

Comment: Have you tried setting style="display:none" instead of visible=false? sometimes,setting visible="false" on a server-side .NET control causes the control not to be rendered on the page at all.

Comment: Is that `btnhomepage` inside some control that remains invisible?

Answer (score 3):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnhomepage" Visible="false" runat="server" 
Text="Goto Homepage" CssClass="cssLoginButton" onclick="btnhomepage_Click"/>
```

when using visible attribute in the mark-up you are forcing your control to be visible=false and stay false forever. asp.net engine render asp.net controls into html control in asp.net page life cycle at **Render** stage. even you had changed the control property in any code behind event

Solution: Don't use makup attribute when setting control behaviour dynamicllay

page life cycle link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx
 http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73728/ASP-NET-Application-and-Page-Life-Cycle

Answer (score 1):

Remove the visible property from the `btnhomepage` button and make it invisible from Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
        this.btnhomepage.Visible = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
btnhomepage.Visible = true;
btnhomepage.Enabled = true;
btnhomepage.Style.Add("display", "block");
```